# FLV player for prettyPhoto (a jQuery based lightbox)

Tags: jquery, flv, flash, flvplayback, streaming-flv-video

I try to find a FLV player that works with PrettyPhoto (http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/). I was wondering if anyone here can recommend a FLV player that would work with PrettyPhoto. A link to a tutorial would be great, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://flowplayer.org/